# How to use Connect Services for event notifications in REST API with PHP SDK?

Tags: docusignapi

Helpers, I want to use Connect services with my DocuSign rest APIs integrated website. Could anyone help me out, Where can I get these in the GitHub? Basically the need is:

Once the document is fully executed, it will be routed via DocuSign connect to a folder which aligns with the name of the employee. This will require work on both the elected system as well as the DocuSign API to configure.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your questions! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No problemo! These days, I suggest using an intermediate PaaS to queue and deliver the webhook notifications to your application which can live safely behind your firewall.

Here's a [blog post on the technique](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4). Note that we have [**PHP** example software](https://github.com/docusign/connect-php-worker-aws) for this technique.

Once your PHP app is notified that an envelope is complete (fully signed), just download the documents from DocuSign and store them in your file system. Easy Peasy!